# How to send message to specific user

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to send messega to specific user.
I looked for facebook developer pages, but I couldn't.

Please tell me how to send(API)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public send API, you should use either the [Send Button social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) or the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) to do what it is that you want.

Comment: You can also use requests if both users authorized your app.